# Show that $f:T^2 \rightarrow T^2$ is topological transitive

Tags: integration, general-topology, dynamical-systems, coordinate-systems, dimensional-analysis

**What is given:**

Let K be a irrational number and $f:T^2 \rightarrow T^2$ be the homeomorphism of the 2-torus given by $f(x,y)=(x+K,x+y)$.

**The exercise:**

Show that for every non-empty, open, $f$-invariant set is dense.

**What I did:**

I did note that I need to prove that $f$ is topological transitive.
So I need to find a point in $T^2$ whose forward orbit is dense in $T^2$.

First I picked the point $(a,b)\in T^2$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.
Then I find that $f(a,b)=(a+K,a+b)$. I do note that the first ordinate is a irrational number and the second one a rational number. Now with the pigeon-hole principle we find that for any $\epsilon >0$ that there are $m,n< \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ such that $m<n$ and $d((x+K)^m,(x+K)^n)<\epsilon$, where $(x+K)^m=(x+k) \circ ...\circ (x+K)$, m times.
Now we have that $(x+K)^{n-m}$ is a rotation by an angle less than $\epsilon$. Thus we find that every forward orbit is dense in $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$.

Now we find that for $(x,y)\in T^2$ its forward orbit is dense in $T^2$. Thus $f$ is topological transitive.

**My question to you:**
I do not belive that my prove it 100% correct. So I was wondering if you guys could give my some tips and maybe could correct me.

Comment: I don't know how to show this without using Fourier Series - have you tried that?

Comment: No i did not. How should I use the Fourier Series?

Comment: You only need to worry about making rigorous the sentence "Now we find that for $(x,y)\in T^2$ its forward orbit is dense in $T^2$." You really don't need all that. I suggest that you draw a few images of a ball and see what happens.